# Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid _grant

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am working on Windows and tried the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/
That worked fine when I tested locally but when uploading it using 
    "mvn appengine:update" I get the following

"Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid
_grant
.'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

The appengine-web.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>spline-1270</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

Any ideas on what is wrong here?
 I want to mention that there was no browser opened to be invited to enter the credentials for Google account.

Thanks,

Sorin

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution: Delete the C:/Users/yourUser/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java". Then re-run mvn appengine:update. It will ask again for credentials.